# How to Extract or Remove Multiple Lists from Master List Using Python

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, list-comprehension

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.isitwp.com/hosting-reviews/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features='lxml')
items = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'entry-content')

for item in items:

    productlist = []
    all_links = []
    all_coupon = []
    all_review = []
    
    # FIND ALL LINKS ON PAGE
    all_links_counter = 0
    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
            current_link = link['href']
            all_links.append(current_link)
    # Remove Duplicate Urls
    s = []
    for i in all_links:
      if i not in s:
          all_links_counter = all_links_counter + 1
          s.append(i)
    #print('All Links Found:', all_links_counter, ' times with Urls:', all_links)
    

    # FIND URL CONTAINING: coupon
    coupon_counter = 0
    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
      if 'coupon' in link.get('href'):
        coupon = link.get('href')
        all_coupon.append(coupon)
    # Remove Duplicate Urls
    s = []
    for i in all_coupon:
      if i not in s:
          coupon_counter = coupon_counter + 1
          s.append(i)
    print('coupon Found:', coupon_counter, ' times with Urls:', all_coupon)


    # FIND URL CONTAINING: review
    review_counter = 0
    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
      if 'review' in link.get('href'):
        review = link.get('href')
        all_review.append(review)
    # Remove Duplicate Urls
    s = []
    for i in all_review:
      if i not in s:
          review_counter = review_counter + 1
          s.append(i)
    print('review Found:', review_counter, ' times with Urls:', all_review)
    print()

    product = {
        'All Links Counter': all_links_counter,
        'All Links': ', '.join(all_links),
        'coupon Counter': coupon_counter,
        'coupon Links': ', '.join(all_coupon),
        'review Counter': review_counter,
        'review Links': ', '.join(all_review),
    }
  
    productlist.append(product)
    print('Product List:\n',product)
```

The above script scrapes the embedded page for URLs and saves the results as follows:

- **all_links** - all links on the page
- **all_coupon** - all links that contain the word *coupon*
- **all_review** - all links that contain the word *review*

I now need a way to identify the balance URLs as below:

**balance_urls = all_links - (all_coupon + all_review)**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use set difference:

```
balance_urls = list(set(all_links).difference(set(all_coupon+all_review)))
```

Or list comprehension if you want to preserve duplicates:

```
balance_urls = [l for l in all_links if l not in (all_coupon+all_review)]
```

Comment: I do not understand what is meant by 'preserve duplicates'. Could you please expand.

Comment: If `all_links` is `["google", "google", "yahoo"]` and `all_coupon` is `["yahoo"]`, the first code gives you `["google"]` and the second gives you `["google", "google"]`

Comment: Thank you for explaining and providing a solution. I will use option 1 as it provides the balance, but also avoids duplicate scenarios in the master list.